# How to kill a specific instance on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, devops

I am working on a POC to deploy some application workloads on PCF platform. I want to simulate auto-recovery of my application scenario where if one instance running the application goes down, PCF would automatically create another one to match my desired capacity.

While trying my options on CLI and PCF application manager, I cannot find any option to manually kill a running instance to generate an artificial failure.

Any idea on how can I do this? Please let me know if I can add more details in my question to be specific and answerable.

Answer (score 3):

You want the `cf restart-app-instance` command.  This will issue an [API call that terminates the indicated app instance](http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/280/apps/terminate_the_running_app_instance_at_the_given_index.html) (index numbers start at one).  The name says "restart", but it just terminates the instance and relies on the platform's natural behavior of restarting the app instance automatically.

Ex: `cf restart-app-instance my-awesome-app 2`

Tested with version `6.34.1+bbdf81482.2018-01-17` of the cf cli, but this command has been around a while.  If for some reason you're stuck on a really old cf cli version and cannot update, you can run `cf curl /v2/apps/$(cf app --guid my-awesome-app)/instances/2`.  This is the same as what's happening in the example above.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, my purpose doesn't solve with this command as it is actually restarting the instance when I run. I want to kill an instance and create a vacuum to test if CF automatically creates an instance if one is unavailable or unhealthy. I am not able to test this scenario using this command.

Comment: @AJavaCoder - I think you're mistaken.  Take a look at the API doc I linked you to.  It says nothing about restarting the app instance.  It's just killing the instance.  The platform will restart your app though, in some cases, very quickly so from what you're saying it sounds like your test is working.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the instance at the index:

`cf curl DELETE /v2/apps/$(cf app APP_NAME --guid)/instances/INDEX_OF_THE_INSTANCE`

Reference: http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/272/apps/terminate_the_running_app_instance_at_the_given_index.html

Wait for sometime, so that CF can recreate the instance.